# Ubuntu 17.10: where can I find libgstinterfaces-0.10.so.0 or something compatible?

Tags: dependencies, shared-library

I'm trying to install Maya 2016 in Kubuntu 17.10 64-bit (though I imagine this issue will affect all flavors of Ubuntu 17.10). I've managed to meet every dependency it has except for one shared library: `libgstinterfaces-0.10.so.0`

This library comes from libstreamer, and Maya 2016 requires a number of other libraries from it. All of them except `libgstinterfaces` can be obtained by installing the `libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0` package. You can then make symlinks with filenames matching the older versions of the library that links to the newer versions, e.g.:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstreamer-1.0.so /usr/lib/libgstreamer-0.10.so.0
```

However, `libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0` does not include any version of `libgstinterfaces`. I'm not sure what I can do to satisfy it. This library was included in older versions of Ubuntu. Is there anyway I can install it from an older repo?

edit: I should have mentioned specifically that `apt-file search libgstinterfaces` returns no results.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to install the packages by using a Linux Mint 17.2 / Ubuntu 14.04 system and download the packages using apt:

```
apt install libgstreamer0.10-0
apt install libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0
```

And then installed both of them with `dpkg` in that order.

That said, I know there's an easier way to get at these packages than to use another Ubuntu installation, but I still don't know what that is.

Comment: Maybe you wanted to say "apt get install" instead of  "apt download".

Answer (score 0):

identify which package it lives in issue

```
apt-file search libgstinterfaces
```

so you will see you can install one of these

```
libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstinterfaces-0.10.so.0
libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstinterfaces-0.10.so.0.25.0
libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstinterfaces-0.10.so
```

I would install the xxxx-dev since header files come with packages ending with -dev

If above search is empty goto  ... Settings -> Software & Updates -> Ubuntu Software -> and checkmark ON that list of software sources ... then do the normal

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

then try the search again

Comment: I should have mentioned originally (and edited my original question to add this) that `apt-file search libgstinterfaces` returns no results at all.

Comment: All the software sources in the dialog are already checked. Is there anyway I can add an older version of Ubuntu's software sources?